# Writing to files inside of a Task which is created by a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, task

So I've come across an interesting issue.  I had to write a utility application that hits a webservice to pull down data and write it to a file. The issue is that I have to make multiple concurrent calls to this webservice with different parameters and write the results to different files. Here is the gist of it in pseudo-code...

```
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string rCode in _config.rCodes) {
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(_config.OutputPath + string.Format(@"\{0}-{1}.csv", rCode, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddHHmmssfff")), false)) {
                <call webservice and write to the output file using tw.WriteLine>
            }
        }
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

The tasks get created, webservices called, and data is getting written however I'm experiencing a collision of sorts. I'm seeing data meant for one file ending up in another file. I feel like each instance of the TextWriter in each created tasks are fighting with each other but in my mind, shouldn't they not because the scope of the TextWriter is the task that it was created in?

I did some researching and someone recommended doing a Parallel.Foreach but I experienced the same issue.  The reason I want to run these concurrently is that the result sets due to our third-party are required every 15 minutes and running in series instead of parallel could push that limit (affecting a public-facing application).  Right now, we're OK but in the busier times of year, this could cause an issue when the data sets grow larger.

Comment: Aside: Your code has *blocking* behaviors and is potentially exhausting the thread pool by starting all tasks at once.  You should rewrite the inner portion to simply return a `Task` instead of creating one.  Then you can `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to allow the TPL to decide how many tasks to start.  (Guillaume is correct on your main question.)

Comment: I did not catch that so thank you. I will attempt this as well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `rCode` is in the outer scope, making it a global variable for sub-tasks.

To correct it, you can do:

```
foreach (string rCode in _config.rCodes)
{
    string code = rCode;
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(_config.OutputPath + string.Format(@"\{0}-{1}.csv", code, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddHHmmssfff")), false)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well then, that would explain it with the scope. Is there a way to do what I'm needing and removing rCode from the outer scope? The DateTime is more for clarity when looking at the files on the destination share since rCode would be unique per foreach.

Comment: You are totally right for the `DateTime`, I will remove it from my answer. I added the code you can use to solve your problem.

Comment: Appreciate that.  This is on my tomorrow list if I can't get to it today to test it out. If it works, you get the checkmark!

Comment: Alright. I'm glad if I can help ;) just remember that foreach(var x ...) is translated by the compiler and the x variable is, in fact, declared "above", or outer, the loop block/scope

Comment: So I am running test-runs to see if we get the duplicate data and so far, no (without any modifications).  I'll keep at it to replicate and then once I get that, I'll go ahead and make the changes.